# ASP.NET View Engine Won't Render Inline ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app. I'm trying to put a value in the ViewBag and write it out to the view. In an attempt to do that, I'm using the `<%= ViewBage.Location %>` syntax as shown below:

```
<article>
    <h2>My Title</h2>

    <section>
        I see that you live in<%= ViewBag.Location %>. 
    </section>
</article>
```

When I run this page, I do not get the rendered view. Instead, I see:

I see that you in  `<%= ViewBag.Location %>.`

Its like the view engine isn't parsing the page. However, I have no idea why this would happen. Can someone please tell me how I can get this resolved?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing

`<%= ViewBag.Location %>`

write it as

`<%: ViewBag.Location %>`

if you are using aspx engine(as it is likely to be as per your question)

for razor engine write it as :

```
@ViewBag.Location
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Now, it prints out `<%: ViewBag.Location %>` without rendering it.

Comment: Yes. In fact, I hard-code `ViewBag.Location = "Test";` in a `@{ ... }` block at the top of the view just to verify. I still get the same behavior.

Comment: The last option you showed worked. Apparently I'm using the Razor engine.